# Does changing the state in the children component, also changes it in the it's parent component?

Tags: reactjs

So, I have this doubt.
[image]

In this project, I need to calculate the expense as the title says. Now I have decided to divide this into 4 components, right now named as component 1 (let's say NetBalance), component 2(HistoryCollection), component 3 (IndividualHistory), and component 4 (NewTransaction). Now I don't know redux or context API, so I am planning to keep my state in App.js level, just because here all of my components needs access to that state. Now my question is, if the state is changed in the children component, let's say in the 4th component (NewTransaction one), then it changes the state in that component, and re-renders the 4th component because of changed state, but does it change that state in its parent component, let's say NetBalance Component?
I know that if my state had changed in the parent component, then its children would also get re-rendered because I would have passed that state as props. But does it happen otherwise?
I think it shouldn't honestly because react follows one way data flow. So the changed data shouldn't travel up in the tree.
But if I am wrong, and it does flow upwards, then doesn't it break its own rule of one way data transfer?
Btw they all share same state, which lives in app.js component and the value of that state lets say (userIncome) is passed as props its child component.

Comment: If I read your question right, then no the state in parent component(s) should not change.

Comment: I think it shouldn't. But my question is, does it change it in parent component?

Comment: Based on your description of your app, each component has its own state, so no.

Comment: So if you are saying that the parent component won't get affected by the setState in its children component, then how do I make the state change in the parent component?

Comment: No, they don't have their own state, they share the same state which lives in App.js

Comment: Oh I thought you said you didn't pass state down, my bad

Comment: Nope, I do pass it down as props :)

Comment: So now does it change that state in the parents component, if that same state is changed in its children component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222103/discussion-between-jason-and-maybenextt1me).

Comment: You can just update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we can all be on the same page about what your code is doing instead of playing 20 questions about where state is. From what you describe of your components they have their own state. `<input onChange = {(e) => this.setState({userIncome: e.currentTarget.value})}>` implies the 4th component has its own state. Then by your own admission "then it changes the state in that component".

Comment: I am sorry that the question is not very clear. I will surely edit it. But they all share the same state which lives in app.js component and is passed as props to all its other children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Each component has its own state. If you'd like to update the parent component's state you would need to pass a method down to the child as a prop to do so.

> **Lifting State Up**
>
> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We
> recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common
> ancestor.

React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bohr-yqzbd?file=/src/App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null
    };
  }
  liftState = (state) => {
    this.setState(state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child liftState={this.liftState} value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Parent value: {props.value}</div>
      <button onClick={() => props.liftState({ value: 5 })}>
        Update Parent's State
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is correct, I tried to explain this in chat to OP

Comment: I think there is a confusion. Every component doesn't have its own state, they all share one state, which lives in app.js component and that state is passed down as props in each component, like state drilling or props drilling, you may say

Comment: @wdm So if I pass down the state as a props to its children state, then what you are saying is that if the children changes the state, then that would change the state in its parent component too. But doesn't it break that one way data flow concept?

Comment: @MayBeNextT1me if you pass the parent's state to a child, it's just props in the child, it doesn't become part of the child's state.

Comment: @wdm Ok, so you mean when I pass my state as props to its children component, then it only gets the value and not the state itself right?

Comment: @MayBeNextT1me you can pass the entire parent's state down to the child and it'll just be props in the child. Changing the values in the child will just change the child's props and nothing else. You shouldn't edit state or props directly though. If you wanted to change props you should have some method that updates the parent component where the props came from. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example...

Parent:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    }
  }

  incrementValue = () => {
    this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return <Child value={this.state.value} incrementValue={this.incrementValue} />
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.incrementValue}>{this.props.value}</button>
  }
}
```

In order for the child to change the state that has been passed down by props, it must receive a function that includes the **this.setState()** as a prop as well.